# How can I use a Session string in a SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, session

I'm trying to use a session string variable as a WHERE clause condition in a SQL command, code below in C#

```
static string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pEAnUtWoRM"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            displayProfiles();
        }
}

private void displayProfiles()
{
       if (Session["email"] != null )
       {
            string email = Convert.ToString(Session["email"]);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Student.Name FROM Student " +
            "LEFT JOIN Mentor ON Student.MentorID = Mentor.MentorID " +
            "WHERE Mentor.EmailAddr = " + email.ToString(), conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet result = new DataSet();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(result, "StudentProfile");
            conn.Close();

            gvProfileList.DataSource = result.Tables["StudentProfile"];
            gvProfileList.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Connection strings and `SqlConnection` work fine (it's not in the method) as I've tested it out on other aspx pages. Error says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The multi-part identifier could not be bound on `da.Fill(result, "StudentProfile");`

Comment: Please do not shout at us (bold sentence are shouting). We know you are new because of your profile. We know you need help, because you have asked a question. :o)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback regarding the way I ask my question and advising me well. Like I've said, I'm new here hence I don't really know the proper way of going about asking a question and I'm not a strong programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because the **query syntax is incorrect** since the value of `email.ToString()` is not appropriately escaped, resulting in a query such as the following one:

```
SELECT
    Student.Name
FROM
    Student
LEFT JOIN
    Mentor ON Student.MentorID = Mentor.MentorID
WHERE
    Mentor.EmailAddr = email@outlook.com
```

My assumption is that your intent was to produce the following query, where the value of `email.ToString()` (e.g. `email@outlook.com`) **is between single quotes**:

```
SELECT
    Student.Name
FROM
    Student
LEFT JOIN
    Mentor ON Student.MentorID = Mentor.MentorID
WHERE
    Mentor.EmailAddr = 'email@outlook.com'
```

A possible fix would be adding a parameter (e.g. `@EmailAddress`) to the SQL command and assigning the email value to it as follows:

```
const string EMAIL_ADDRESS_PARAMETER_NAME = "@EmailAddress";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Student.Name FROM Student " +
    "LEFT JOIN Mentor ON Student.MentorID = Mentor.MentorID " +
    $"WHERE Mentor.EmailAddr={EMAIL_ADDRESS_PARAMETER_NAME}", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add(EMAIL_ADDRESS_PARAMETER_NAME, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
```

Comment: The **@EmailAddress** is defined by **constant** variable **EMAIL_ADDRESS_PARAMETER_NAME**, which is recommended instead of having multiple strings with the same value in different parts of the code, which may easily lead to bugs (e.g. typos, change the string in one place but not the other). The **$** is used for string interpolation. And the parameter values is being added in the last line **cmd.Parameters.Add...**. There is no input being concatenated in the query. I left the + in the question code, which I assume was applied to prevent lines to be too long.

Comment: In addition to better security, parameterized queries eliminate the need to enclose literals (or not) depending on the type, eliminate the need to escape quotes within strings, avoid the need to format date string literals in a particular way, do not require decimal separators (which vary by culture), improve performance by promoting execution plan cache reuse, and result in cleaner code that's easier to maintain.